# Host key verification failed when git pull on the vm

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

I'm doing `git pull origin master` in my company's vm server to pull latest change from a repository in gitlab hosted inside my company. and I get this error:

```
$ git pull origin master
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I used `ssh -A batch@thisbox.vm` to login to this vm, and I have verified in my local that `ssh-add -l` have the key added

```
$ ssh-add -l
1234 SHA256:xxxxxx firstname lastname - aa - 1233 (RSA)
```

and in my local I can do any type of `git` operation to this repo. I also verified that in the vm the remote master points to the right repo

```
$ git remote -v
origin  correct_repo_address (fetch)
origin  correct_repo_address (push)
```

what's wrong here that I can not do `git pull` on the box? appreciate for any help!

Comment: `ssh-add` isn't relevant here; it doesn't deal with host keys. When you run `ssh -A batch@thisbox.vm` and successfully connect, are you running it as the same user as when git runs? How is git configured to use ssh? Is git connecting to port 22 or some other port?

Comment: @Kenster I'm a bit new to ssh so can you elaborate the detail procedure/commands that I can use to triage?